# How to construct a parent class with an object created in the child constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a subclass that knows what type of object to send the parent class, but I can't figure out how to create it so the parent can keep the object around without making an extra copy in the parent class constructor.

```
class Thing {
...some stuff...
};

class Parent {
private:
  Thing & thing;

public:
  Parent(Thing & in_thing):thing(in_thing);
};

class Child : public Parent {
  public:
    // Does my Thing object get created on the stack here and therefor I can't keep a reference or pointer to it in the parent class?
    Child():Parent(Thing()){};
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

I don't know how to try this to see if it's OK because it could potentially work fine for some amount of time even if the memory isn't valid to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an object in stack memory, create one using heap memory. The parent can own the object.

```
class Parent {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing;;

  public:
    Parent(Thing* in_thing): thing(in_thing);
};
```

and

```
class Child : public Parent {
  public:
    Child():Parent(new Thing()){};
}
```

Using a pointer also allows `Child` to create a sub-type of `Thing`. Some times you need that.

```
class ChildThing : public Thing { ... };

class Child : public Parent {
  public:
    Child():Parent(new ChildThing()){};
}
```

Comment: I had assumed you couldn't call new in the child class initialzation list - do you have a link to the rules of what can and cannot go in the initialization list?  You can't put arbitrary code in there, right?

Comment: @xaxxon. the expression `new Thing()` is used as an argument to initialize the base class, `Parent`. Any expression that can be converted to `Thing*` is valid there. That is different from what can go in the initialization list. You can only use base classes and members in the initialization list. But the values used to initialize them can be any valid expression.

Comment: So I could potentially call some static method that returns the object?   like `Thing::create_thing()` (if it existed)?   How far does that go?  Can I say `rand() > 5 ? new Thing(0) : new Thing(1)` ?

Comment: @xaxxon, yes and yes.

Comment: Neat.  For some reason i thought the rules of what went in there were incredibly restrictive.   Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @xaxxon, you are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.